# Is it possibile to arrange a time series in the way that a specific autocorrleation is created?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a file containing 2,500 random numbers. Is it possible to rearrange these saved numbers in the way that a specific autocorrelation is created? Lets say, autocorrelation to the lag 1 of 0.2, autocorrelation to the lag 2 of 0.4, etc.etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

To be more specific:

The time series of a daily return in percent of an asset has the following characteristics that I am trying to recreate:

1. Leptokurtic, symmetric distribution, let's say centered at a daily return of zero
2. No significant autocorrelations (because the sign of a daily return is not predictable)
3. Significant autocorrleations if the time series is squared

The aim is to produce a random time series which satisfies all these three characteristics. The only two inputs should be the leptokurtic distribution (this I have already created) and the specific autocorrelation of the squared resulting time series (e.g. the final squared time series should have an autocorrelation at lag 1 of 0.2).

I only know how to produce random numbers out of my own mixed-distribution. Naturally if I would square this resulting time series, there would be no autocorrelation. I would like to find a way which takes this into account.

Answer (score 8):

Generally the most straightforward way to create autocorrelated data is to generate the data so that it's autocorrelated. For example, you could create an auto correlated path by always using the value at p-1 as the mean for the random draw at time period p.

Rearranging is not only hard, but sort of odd conceptually. What are you really trying to do in the end? Giving some context might allow better answers.

Comment: I only have a good answer because of these stupid cleat marks up my back where I tried to do... um... this type of stuff... in the past :O

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Alright, what I am trying to do is to simulate daily returns of a specific stock.


I have created a mixed-distribution of daily returns of a specific stock (mixture between two normal and one t-distribution). This reflects the "leptokurtosis" of stock returns. Now I would like to create a time series out of this mixed-distribution which is not correlated when it comes to normal returns but has a specific autocorrelation when it comes to squared returns.

Does any one see a way here?

With kind regards,
Christian

Comment: One asset where the price at time t (Pt) is a function of (Pt-1)^2? Um... use the value of (Pt-1)^2 as the mean for the price return draw at Pt? Which kinda sounds like my answer above. Further info/examples are needed in order to help any more.

Comment: Hey JD,
I hope I don't get you wrong (please correct me if I do so). I am talking about the return of an asset in percent, not about the price of the asset itself. The price of an asset has always significant autocorrelations and I thought it was defined as P(t) = P(t-1) + Noise. I have edited my original question to be more specific.

Comment: Chris, I was confused as I didn't understand the bit about it being NOT autocorrelated unless the returns were squared. That's tricky. And it also takes the question totally out of a programming problem and into a math problem. Once you solve the maths, you'll be able to seek help in solving the encoding of the maths into R :) But I'll still ponder this as it's turning into a fun riddle.

Comment: A highly uninformed stab in the dark: I wonder if you can do find a tool to simulate from a GARCH process, which is dealing with autocorrelated volatility, which is more or less (very approximately) equivalent to the autocorrelation in the square of a zero-mean variable ... ?

Answer (score 4):

There are functions for simulating correlated data. `arima.sim()` from stats package and `simulate.Arima()` from the forecast package.

`simulate.Arima()` has the advantages that (1.) it can simulate seasonal ARIMA models (maybe sometimes called "SARIMA") and (2.) It can simulate a continuation of an existing timeseries to which you have already fit an ARIMA model. To use `simulate.Arima()`, you do need to already have an `Arima` object.

UPDATE:

type `?arima.sim` then scroll down to "examples".

Alternatively:

`install.packages("forecast")`

`library(forecast)`

`fit <- auto.arima(USAccDeaths)`

`plot(USAccDeaths,xlim=c(1973,1982))`

`lines(simulate(fit, 36),col="red")`

Comment: Care to give a short example?

Comment: Roman Luštrik, type `?arima.sim` then scroll down to "examples".
Alternatively:
`install.packages("forecast");
library(forecast);
fit <- auto.arima(USAccDeaths);
plot(USAccDeaths,xlim=c(1973,1982))
lines(simulate(fit, 36),col="red")
`

Comment: ^I new how, I would use new lines instead of the semicolons.